# How to mine for motifs in R with iGraph

Tags: r, graph, igraph

I'm trying to mine for 3-node motifs in R using the package `igraph`.  I would like to retrieve the number of motifs for each individual vertex in the graph, which does not appear possible from the graph.motifs() function.

So, for the example graph:

```
testGraph = barabasi.game(10, 
m = 5,
power = 2, 
out.pref = TRUE,
zero.appeal = 0.5,
directed = TRUE)
```

I can use `graph.motifs()` to count the total number of each 3-node motif in the entire graph:

```
graph.motifs(testGraph, 
size = 3)
```

> [1]  0  0 26  0 16  0  2 58  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0

But I would like to know the individual vertex participation.  So, how many motifs (and what type) does vertex 1 participate in?  Does anybody know a simple way to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a quick how-to.

It you are interested in the triads of vertex *A*, then first create the induced subgraph that contains *A* and its immediate neighbors. You can do this via `neighborhood()` and `induced.subgraph()` or simply with `graph.neighborhood()`.

Then find the motifs in this subgraph, but not with `graph.motifs()`, but rather with `triad.census()`, because that counts all possible triples, even a non-connected ones.

Then remove *A* from this subgraph, and call `triad.census()` again. The difference of the two count vector will be exactly the motifs that include *A*.

Comment: I'll leave the actual code as an exercise. :) But please comment here if you encounter any problems.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a self-contained example of Gabor's solution:

```
testGraph = barabasi.game(10, 
    m = 5,
    power = 0.6, 
    out.pref = TRUE,
    zero.appeal = 0.5,
    directed = TRUE)

# Label nodes to more easily keep track during subsets/deletions
V(testGraph)$name = c('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten')

subGraph = graph.neighborhood(testGraph, order = 1, V(testGraph)[1], mode = 'all')[[1]]
allMotifs = triad.census(subGraph)
removeNode = delete.vertices(subGraph, 'one')
node1Motifs = allMotifs - triad.census(removeNode)
```