# How to plot Motifs in igraph?

Tags: r, graph, igraph, ppi

I use igraph package to get motifs in Protein-Protein interaction network, It has a vector output, But I need plot or draw of motifs, figure of motifs.

code in R:

```
 motifs(graph_object, size = 3)
```

output:

> [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374534/how-to-mine-for-motifs-in-r-with-igraph) NA NA  5  3

How to I get plot of motifs in R and igraph? Here have we four motifs?

Note: This question is different from [How to mine for motifs in R with iGraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374534/how-to-mine-for-motifs-in-r-with-igraph)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mine for motifs in R with iGraph](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374534/how-to-mine-for-motifs-in-r-with-igraph)

Comment: No, my question is different.

Comment: The four motifs on three nodes are the empty graph, one edge, a 2-star, and a triangle.  The first two motifs are not fully connected so the counts returned are NAs.  Are you asking how to plot the 2-stars and triangles with node labels?

Comment: Yes, I want to second two motifs figure as a plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construct the motif that you want to search for as a "template graph" (for instance, create a triangle graph), then use `subgraph_isomorphisms` to find all the mappings from the vertices of the template graph from the vertices of your protein-protein interaction network, and `induced_subgraph` combined with `lapply` to transform the list of mappings into the actual motifs. Example:

```
> pattern <- graph.full(3)
> my.graph <- grg.game(100, 0.2)        # just an example graph, use yours
> iso <- subgraph_isomorphisms(pattern, my.graph)      # takes a while
> motifs <- lapply(iso, function (x) { induced_subgraph(my.graph, x) })
```

`motifs` will then be a list of graphs, and you can plot them one by one using `plot()`.

Comment: Thank you. It is that thing I need.